# C++ file name with space causes error in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

When I write a C++ program with the file name `Hello World.cpp` in Visual Studio Code I got some errors:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  cout<<"Hello World!!!"<<endl;

return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
g++.exe: error: Hello: No such file or directory
g++.exe: error: World.cpp: No such file or directory
g++.exe: error: World: No such file or directory
g++.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

But when I rename the file without space like `HelloWorld.cpp`, then I did not get any type of error. And I use the latest updated Visual Studio Code and MingW compiler.

But I wanted to use filename with space. How do I resolve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Enclose the filename in quotes

Comment: As you can see in the screenshot, the compiler command looks like `g++ Hello World.cpp`, so it'll search for _two_ files called `Hello` and `World.cpp`. As you say, the simplest solution is to use file names without spaces. A "proper" solution would require editing the compiler command

Comment: From experience - most tools and utilities can be made to cope with spaces in file and path names.  However by default most tools and utilities __don't__ cope with spaces in file and path names.  Therefore avoid spaces in path and file names unless you enjoy configuring your build tools.

Comment: If you have your heart set on having a space in the name, and you don't want to configure your build tools, replace the space (U+0020) with a non-breaking space (U+00A0).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows, try configuring settings like this in your **Setting.JSON**

```
"code-runner.executorMap": {
    "cpp": "cd $dir && g++ \"$fileName\" -o \"$fileNameWithoutExt.exe\" && & \"$dir$fileNameWithoutExt.exe\""
}
```

Pay attention to the extra '&' character.

If you are using Unix based system, try this (I haven't tested, but I think this would work):

```
"code-runner.executorMap": {
    "cpp": "cd $dir && g++ \"$fileName\" -o \"$fileNameWithoutExt\" && \"$dir$fileNameWithoutExt\""
}
```

Comment: `"code-runner.executorMap": {
    "cpp": "cd $dir && g++ \"$fileName\" -o \"$fileNameWithoutExt\" && \"./$fileNameWithoutExt\""
}`
Will this work in case of Linux?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the corrected version:

1. Install the Code Runner extension in VS Code.
2. Press Ctrl + Shift + P to open the Command Palette.
3. Type "Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON)" and open the JSON file.
4. Paste the following code into it.

```
  "code-runner.runInTerminal": true,
  "code-runner.executorMap": {
    "cpp": "cd $dir && g++ \"$fileName\" -o \"$fileNameWithoutExt\" && \"./$fileNameWithoutExt\""
  }
```

This method works in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

Answer (score -2):

You can simply remove space from the filename to run the program like `Hello_world.cpp` or `HelloWorld.cpp`. Spaces in the file name are not allowed in vs code.