# error: source file or directory not found:

Tags: kotlin, visual-studio-code

I've been trying.g to get Kotlin to work on vs code after following all the steps from this YouTube video https://youtu.be/QeVl8fXteI0 and someone's.
It keeps showing me this[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTTm2.png)

Please how can I solve this?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Visual Studio, but I'd guess from the error that it has trouble with source filenames containing spaces.

Spaces in filenames — and indeed, in class names — are valid in Kotlin, but very unusual.  (In Java, for comparison, spaces are *not* allowed in class names, and hence neither in filenames.  But a quick test with `kotlinc` shows that Kotlin allows both.)

So the simplest thing to try would be to rename your file to remove the space.

Beyond that, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69043901/c-file-name-with-space-causes-error-in-visual-studio-code) seems to be related.