Why there is a need to not add a space in the name of file in vs code cpp?
In the beginning, I was working on my code and I use to run a piece of code at random and suddenly I found that the was a kind of FATAL Error compiler showing in the terminal and I used to search on web, later on my fried told me to not put any space in the name of project. In the meanwhile, our discussing turned into something else because of no valid reason for the logic that he presented.

the relative error


g++ adjacency matrix will fail, but this should work (under Windows): g++ "adjacency matrix", see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69043901/c-file-name-with-space-causes-error-in-visual-studio-code

P.S: Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?   This is, seeing the second image, a sure must read. Apart from that I still do not see a space in the filename (even when looking closer to that image .... )

Not an expert but this is my thought regarding this issue.
In shell/command line, every word acts as an input or option passed to the command. So if your file has space in name it basically becomes 2 different inputs. adjacency and matrix. Most compilation would include some sort of execution like that and so will throw an error.

More over, if there are space in the name, the filename/path must be enclosed with single/double quote in order to avoid shell expansion.

It's not a VSC problem, you're using a poorly written extension ("Code Runner") to run your code.
When compiling a file with spaces in the name, the filename must be quoted (as shown in the other answers). The extension should do this automatically, but it doesn't.

yep. and cpptools supports similar run file functionality so I don't see the need for coderunner anyway.

It is possible to have spaces in file and directory names, but you need to handle them in command lines. There are two ways of doing this:

Put the whole filename withing single or double quotes:

g++ 'adjacency matrix.cpp' -o adj


Escape the space with backslash:

g++ adjacency\ matrix.cpp -o adj

Without doing this, the shell will pass 'adjency' and 'matrix.cpp' as two separate arguments to g++ which in total will get four arguments: 'adjency', 'matrix.cpp', '-o', 'adj'.
